# How to choose a Peltier module and heat sink to cool a MOSFET down to -40°C?

Tags: mosfet, heatsink, peltier, cooling

I need to cool a MOSFET down to -40°C, but I really know nothing about thermal devices.

Could anyone teach me how to calculate the specific parameters that can help me choose the right Peltier module and heat sink?

Details: I built a double pulse test circuit to test MOSFET loss, so the basic idea is cooling the MOSFET first, then apply power to the circuit.

Comment: How much power does your MOSFET dissipate?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It is BSC032N04LS. But I think it doesn't matter because my idea is to cool the MOSFET first and then apply the power over it.

Comment: Well, do you want to _keep_ it cool? But any good supplier will have a calculator on their web site to help you choose the best device(s).

Comment: You are really scratching the bottom of the barrel here. IIRC the maximum temp difference of common Peltier cells is about 70K, that means that the hot side of the cell must be at most 30°C. And you'll need a whole lot of thermal insulation with such a deltaT. I think your goals will be easier to achieve using a stack of two or three cells (google for "stacked peltier cells").

Comment: Yes I want to keep it cool during my test. The problem is I know little about thermal devices and I don't know what the website is talking about. For example, the website offers me a graph of Qc against operating voltage, but I really dont know waht Qc is and how it affect my design.

Comment: How much power for how long?

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in the past for deep cold transient testing:

Get a TEC and bolt to the device. Put in a very cold freezer, then turn on the TEC. If you can start with a -20°C freezer a TEC at no load should have little trouble hitting -40°C. Then quickly do your measurements before the device can heat up from the load.

For really cold get dry ice, but it sounds like you won't need that here, although it would let you avoid the TEC entirely.